# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_Get_ZINTLL, Line 36 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an incorrect syntax error on line `35/36` in the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afm.SP_Get_ZINTLL
AS

Begin
SELECT   DISTINCT ls_id AS ZINTLSID_0 
        ,'ARC' AS ZINTSRCCODE_0 ,landlord_tenant  
        ,date_start
        ,coalesce(ls.bl_id, ls.pr_id) as [ZINTLSTYPE_0]
        ,coalesce(date_end, GETDATE()) as [ZINTSTRDAT_0]
        ,tn_name
        ,ld_name
        ,isnull(purchase_requisition, 0) as [ZINTBPRNUM_0]
        ,coalesce(ls.asset_id,0) as [ZINTBPSNUM_0]
        , ZINTCCE1_0 = ls.ls_id 
        --init_value defaulting to JHB removed 2018-06-22
            SELECT dim_code 
            FROM afm.za_dim_lookup
            WHERE init_value = coalesce(ls.registered_office, '') 
                AND dim_type = 'DT1'
        ,ZINTCCE2_0  = ls.ls_id
            SELECT dim_code
            FROM afm.za_dim_lookup
            WHERE init_value = 'DEFAULT_LS'
                AND dim_type = 'DT2'
            ) 

end
```

Comment: Which line is `35/36`?

Comment: You have a lot of selects here without from ?

Comment: Try running the same select query directly from sql management studio.

Comment: hi Jen i am getting a syntax error from this line        ,ZINTCCE2_0  = ls.ls_id
   SELECT dim_code

Comment: This code has a lot of problems.  I would suggest rebuilding the procedure piece-by-piece, getting each part to work before moving on.  Start with Select ls_id.  Get that working, then add the next field, and so on.

Comment: A `WHERE` doesn't work like a `SELECT`. you need to use an `AND` or `OR` to separate clauses, not a comma (`,`)

Comment: I believe the two SELECT from ...Lookup are meant to be sub-queries.

Comment: Side note, don't use `sp_` as the stored procedure name prefix. That is used to denote system stored procedures.

Comment: To expand on what @DanGuzman is saying: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

As a pure guess, the 2 `SELECT`s are meant to be subqueries, then this is probably what you are after...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ls_id AS ZINTLSID_0,
       'ARC' AS ZINTSRCCODE_0,
       landlord_tenant,
       date_start,
       COALESCE(ls.bl_id, ls.pr_id) AS [ZINTLSTYPE_0],
       COALESCE(date_end, GETDATE()) AS [ZINTSTRDAT_0],
       tn_name,
       ld_name,
       ISNULL(purchase_requisition, 0) AS [ZINTBPRNUM_0],
       COALESCE(ls.asset_id, 0) AS [ZINTBPSNUM_0],
       ls.ls_id AS ZINTCCE1_0,
       --init_value defaulting to JHB removed 2018-06-22
       (SELECT dim_code
        FROM afm.za_dim_lookup
        WHERE init_value = COALESCE(ls.registered_office, '')
          AND dim_type = 'DT1'
          AND ZINTCCE2_0 = ls.ls_id), --AS ...??? Will this only return 1 row?
       (SELECT dim_code
        FROM afm.za_dim_lookup
        WHERE init_value = 'DEFAULT_LS'
          AND dim_type = 'DT2') --AS ...??? Will this only return 1 row?
FROM ...;
```

This is probably going to generate more errors though (I suspect a sub-query returned more than 1 row error would be one).

You would be far better off providing sample data and expected results, as well as your **full** query.

Comment: I don't think the ,ZINTCCE2_0  = ls.ls_id  is meant to be a condition of the subquery.  It is another field of the main query.  We can see an almost identical line above.

Comment: Indeed, it's a complete guess. It won't have a syntax error though, so might push the OP in the right direction.